# Read private key file (.pkcs8) with OpenSSL.NET

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, openssl-net

I am using the OpenSSL .NET project (https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net).
In C++ code, I have read the private key from a .pkcs8 file (`30 82 02 4b 02 01 20 30 81 ...`) to a `EVP_PKEY` struct like this:

```
FILE* pFile = NULL;
pFile = fopen("myfile.pkcs8", "rb");
if (pFile)
{
  EVP_PKEY* m_pEVP_PKEY;
  m_pEVP_PKEY = d2i_PrivateKey_fp(pFile, NULL);
}
```

But I can't seem to find an equivalent to `d2i_PrivateKey_fp` in the .NET project.
How would I read this private key to a `EVP_PKEY` struct?
Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like that library has ported that API, yet. The project also doesn't look like it currently active.

Comment: Thx for the info. Is it possible to use other functions that have already been ported in the project to make this work?